# elasticsearch - Any performance issue by using custom value as _id

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

We are implementing search on candidate data of about 10 mil records and we are planning to use candidate email ID as primary key for each record in elasticsearch.

Can we use emailAddress as _id in elasticsearch or we should only use elastic generated random id only?
Is there any performance impact if we use custom id?
Performance impact on indexing and searching?
Are we over loading elasticsearch by using custom id?

Regards,
Jayesh Bhoyar

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong in using an email address (preferably a hash thereof) as a document ID. You might still want to read this: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html

Comment: Thank you, but I already gone through the article and then posted this question.. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, you should have referenced it in your question, since this is good material :-) Basically, IDs can be anything, but the main thing you want to make sure is that they spread out evenly across all the index shards so you have a well-balanced index.

Comment: we have used lucene friend number as ES ID to avoid any performance issue